# Is there a way to differentiate between tags of the same name fetched from different remotes?

Tags: git

I'm using read-tree to get over the bare repo can't use submodules issue when pushing to a server to deploy but now I'm slightly stuck where two repos I'm working with have tagged version numbers. What I need is some tree-ish way to refer to a tag including the remote name but I can't see anything obvious. Something like:

```
git read-tree --prefix=api/framework/ -u framework/1.6.5
```

Where framework is one of the remotes. But only this works:

```
git read-tree --prefix=api/framework/ -u 1.6.5
```

However another remote my have that same tag... and git tag lists all tags in one list

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The root of the problem here is that tags don't have a "remote tag name space" the way branches do.

When you run `git fetch`, it consults the remote and brings over references according to the `git config --get-all remote.name.fetch` line(s).  Normally there is only one:

```
$ git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Thus, `git fetch` brings over `refs/heads/master` but installs it as `refs/remotes/origin/master`.

Git always knows to look in the `remotes/` name space for "remote branches".

When you run `git fetch --tags`, this adds:

```
refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

as a refspec (and also bypasses the `remote.origin.fetch` part), but it brings over all the tags into the (single) `refs/tags/` name-space.  In other words, the remote is not part of the name; you and the remote all use a single global "tag" name space.

You can configure your repo differently, adding an extra line:

```
git config --add remote.origin.fetch '+refs/tags/*:refs/rtags/origin/*'
```

This creates a new local reference name-space, `refs/rtags/`.  Since you've put the name of the remote in as the top level entry under `rtags`, you can configure a *different* sub-space for another remote:

```
git config --add remote.rmt2.fetch '+refs/tags/*:refs/rtags/rmt2/*'
```

Now when you run `git fetch origin` it will bring origin's tags in as `rtags/origin/`, and `git fetch rmt2` will bring those rmt2's tags into `rtags/rmt2/`.

Git does *not* know about `rtags` (we just made it up here!) so you have to refer to these as `rtags/origin/foo`, etc., or even `refs/rtags/origin/foo` in some (rare) cases.

(Omit the `+` to prevent force-updating of tags.  This is not generally supposed to happen—users are not supposed to move tags from one SHA-1 to another—but the `+` in the `fetch` line means "if they changed it, take the new one".  Since you're now sticking them into a "remote tags" space, I assume you probably want them to force-update, a la remote branch names.  Note that these will also auto-prune, just like remote branches, if you run `git fetch -p` or `git remote prune`.  That's independent of the `+`.)

Comment: +1 great explanation! I guess that means if you have similarly named tags across multiple remotes, the tags setup locally take precedence when a list of tags is requested using `git tag -l`.

Comment: Yes, since it lacks the `+`, the auto-refspec for `git fetch --tags` won't overwrite any tag you already have.  (It would be bad if it did!)

Comment: Great explanation yet again @torek.

Answer (score 1):

I've just found a partial answer although it's not really as nice as referring to the tag itself:

```
git ls-remote --tags framework
```

Then see the sha of the tag you want and use that. Happy to be educated about a better way.